# MySQL not allowing remote connections using Python3 mysql.connector on Raspbian-Stretch

Tags: mysql, linux-networking, python, mariadb, raspbian

I am trying to allow connections using mysql.connector from a specific machine to a [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/about) server, within the local network.

Ideally, I would like to create an account limited to a single IP and DB.

For simplicity, I have tried the following wildcard approach:

```
CREATE USER 'foo'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'foobar';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'foo'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

`SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE user='foo';`

```
+--------+-----------+
| user   | host      |
+--------+-----------+
| foo    | %         |
+--------+-----------+
```

Using this basic, Python test script:

```
import mysql.connector

class DBConnect:
  def __init__(self):
    config={
      'user':'foo',
      'password':'foobar',
      'host':'192.168.x.xxx',
      'port':3306,
      'database':'foo',
      'raise_on_warnings':True
    }
    self.__db=self.__connect(config)

  def __connect(self,config):
    try:
      return mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
      print(str(err))
      return False

db=DBConnect()
```

I receive the following error:

`1130: Host '192.168.x.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server`

I have read about [changing the bind-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664091/mariadb-not-allowing-remote-connections) and followed various setup guides such as that in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html) for adding new users but I still cannot get a successful connection.

The bind-address can be found in the `50-server.cnf` file. It is set to `127.0.0.1` but if changed to, for example, `0.0.0.0` the server restart fails:

`systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`
`systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.37 database server`

*`skip-networking` is not present in any of the config files*

With the bind-address set to `127.0.0.1` running `netstat -anp | grep 3306` returns:

`tcp  0  0 127.0.0.1:3306      0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  1790/mysqld`
`tcp  0  0 192.168.x.xxx:3306  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  19490/mysqld`

This leads me to believe the database server is indeed listening for connections within the LAN?

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: You have two different copies of mysqld running. Stop both of them and then try again.

Comment: Many thanks for this, @MichaelHampton! That's got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping both of the `mysqld` processes will allow for the `50-server.cnf` file to be modified.

The mysql process can then be successfully restarted. Remote connections will now be accepted.

*Credit to MichaelHampton*